# From Discrete to continuous Probablities

Tags: mathematical-statistics

How does one define Density function for a continuous Random variable?
What is the role of density function?
How do achieve Density from mass?

Comment: Continuous random variables are NOT discrete. It does not make sense to talk about 'mass' here since the sample space is a continuum.

Comment: Yes i know that

Comment: Your third question is irrelevant then?

Comment: This sounds like a self-study question. Could you add the tag, read the [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-study) and detail what you do not understand about densities, i.e., where you get stuck?

Comment: i want to know how do we build continuous curve from histograms

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. We don't "build continuous curves from histograms". Can you clarify what you're after?